# SQL query to retrieve a row based on another row in same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `statuses` with columns `id`, `name` and `parent_id`.

I want to retrieve a row with `parent_id = 9`.
If there is not such a row, I want to get the row with `id = 9`.

Can I get this with single query?

Answer (score 2):

You could select both rows, order the `parent_id` matches on top, and grab the top row:

```
select  *
from    statuses
where   parent_id = 9 or id = 9
order by
        case when parent_id = 9 then 1 else 2 end
limit   1
```

If `id` is not a primary key, you could try a `union` where the second half is only executed if the first half is empty:

```
select  *
from    statuses
where   parent_id = 9
union all
select  *
from    statuses
where   id = 9
        and not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    statuses
        where   parent_id = 9
        )
```

Comment: Actually, I think, you could combine the two to obtain a third solution with `WHERE` like this: `WHERE parent_id = 9 OR id = 9 AND NOT EXISTS (...)` (I assume `AND` has higher priority than `OR` in PostgreSQL.)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  ISNULL(SP.id, S.parent_id)
FROM
  Statuses S
LEFT JOIN 
  Statuses SP on S.parent_id=SP.id
WHERE
  S.parent_id = 9
```

Comment: There is no `ISNULL()` in PostgreSQL, use the standard `COALESCE()` instead. This assumes that a row with `id = 9` exists if a row with `parent_id = 9` exists - which would make sense, but is not defined here. Aslo the question asks to return "a row", this answer returns a set of IDs instead.

Answer (score 1):

Either of @Andomar's answers will work. Just be sure to use [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-explain.html) to figure out which one is actually faster once you have your table populated. In fact, it would be nice if you could update your post with the results of which was faster based on a few [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-explain.html)'s.

1. SELECT VERSION();
2. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM statuses;
3. And the last line from EXPLAIN ANALYZE ${QUERY};

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from statuses
  where parent_id = 9 or id = 9
  order by case when parent_id = 9 then 1 else 2 end
  limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler, faster:

```
SELECT * FROM COALESCE(
     (SELECT s FROM statuses s WHERE parent_id = 9 LIMIT 1)
    ,(SELECT s FROM statuses s WHERE id = 9 LIMIT 1)
    )
```

If none of the IDs exist, this query returns a row of type `statuses` filled with `NULL` values, while the other solutions here so far return *no row*. Because that's what happens when you call
`SELECT * FROM NULL::statuses`.

#### Explanation

`COALESCE` cannot operate on `rows` per se, a sub-query in place of a variable is expected to return one column only. If you try:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
     (SELECT * FROM statuses WHERE parent_id = 9 LIMIT 1)
    ,(SELECT * FROM statuses WHERE id = 9 LIMIT 1)
    )
```

You get

> ERROR: subquery must return only one column

However, for every table in PostgreSQL a composite type of the same name exists. You can have the subqueries return the whole row as composite type and expand the type afterwards. That's what the query does.

I ran a quick benchmark with a similar real life table of 70k rows in PostgreSQL 9.1.4, both *unique ID columns indexed*. I tested all three cases: `parent_id` exists, `id` exists, none exists. This query is slightly faster than other solution here. I also tried a fixed equivalent of @Parkyprg's incorrect answer and a simplified version of what @Endy and @Andomar posted:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    statuses
WHERE   parent_id = 9 OR id = 9
ORDER   BY (id <> 9);
```

.. which could be faster on tables *without* indexes.